# Firebase 3.4.1 prevents error-messages?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im using firebase 3.4.1 - 
I work on an app to authenticate with google sign on.
All works great, but why doesnt the console show any errors after the function onAuthStateChanged() ?

When i force an error by calling an not existing function inside it, the console dont show anything, but the script stops as expected.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  fghfg();
  if (user) {
    account.init(user);
  } else {
    account.init();
  }
});
```

fghfg() will stop the script. but there is no log-message?!

any ideas?

Comment: It's a well known issue. Errors thrown in onAuthStateChanged will be swallowed. The issue has been reported to Firebase Auth team.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Im now using a workaround for this firebase-intern issue.
Just placed a try-catch-block inside the "onAuthStateChanged()". All Errors inside it will now be console-logged. Hope it will help someone.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  try {
    if (user) {
     account.init(user);
    } else {
      account.init();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```